# Access to the path is denied ... Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Been having ASP.NET issues all morning, and now I got a new one, with this

```
string filepath = "";
filepath = Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["fileDownloadable"]);
if (filepath != null)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyPDF.pdf");
    Response.WriteFile(filepath);
    Response.ContentType = "";
    Response.End();
}
```

gives me an error on line 18 which is `Response.WriteFile(filepath);` and it says Access to the path is denied....why is it doing this?

The `Request.QueryString["fileDownloadable"]` comes from this code...

`<li><a href="./DownloadableProducts.aspx?fileDownloadable=/downloadableProducts/MyPDF.pdf" runat="server">IPC Client Personal Financial Website Feb 12</a></li>`

I checked the permissions on the folder and they have the same kind of permissions has every other folder in my root.

Any suggestions please?

I ran this code inbetween my code behind to see if the file exist..

```
if(File.Exists(filepath)){
}
```

and it ran the page without an error but no functionally of the page wasnt working, this tells me that the filepath does not exist.

Comment: Clear out your cache and re-open your browser, esp. if you're been testing over a period of time in same browser window. This fixed same problem for me.

Comment: You checked the folder but did you check the individual file you're trying to download to see if it has the correct permission?

Comment: So is it throwing an access denied exception? Or is it the error being written to the console?

Comment: Check what user the `Response.WriteFile` runs under (Environment.UserName) and what exact value of `filepath` is (could be mapping to some other path instead on you expect).

Comment: You do know this code allows for downloading arbitrary files in your website, right?

Comment: Yeah... I'd like a copy of web.config please

Comment: I tried cache and re-open my browser and that didnt work, The file in the folder has the write permissions....

Comment: I dont understand "So is it throwing an access denied exception? Or is it the error being written to the console?" I am new to ASP.NET

Comment: I dont understand "Check what user the Response.WriteFile runs under (Environment.UserName) and what exact value of filepath is (could be mapping to some other path instead on you expect)."

Answer (score 0):

Access to the path is likely being denied because it probably doesn't exist. Before simply blasting the file out into `Response.WriteFile` you should perform at least a check to see if the file exists first. This will also give you the opportunity of making sure that the path it's attempting to get will work.

Also keep in mind that it's not going to be aware of the "relative" path you're working on within the scope of the web application. You should make sure that you use either `Server.MapPath` or some configuration setting to ensure that your `filepath` variable looks like an absolute path on the OS such as `E:\Inetpub\wwwroot\...`.